# UnexpectedParameter MessageGroupId for SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have created a FIFO SQS queue.
When sending a message to the queue using the below params,

```
var params= {
    MessageBody: payload, 
    QueueUrl: sqsURL + body.device + ".fifo"
}
sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, res) { 
    err ? callback(err) : callback(null, res);
});
```

I get a warning that says "missing parameter messagegroupid"
[image]

I then proceed to add in MessageGroupId into my params.

```
var params= {
    MessageBody: payload,
    MessageGroupId: "posts",
    QueueUrl: sqsURL + body.device + ".fifo"
}
sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, res) { 
    err ? callback(err) : callback(null, res);
});
```

[image]
SQS then throws me "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'MessageGroupId' found in params".

Am confused by this set of conflicting instructions.
I'm using the same SDK region in both my createQueue and sendMessage command.

```
var sqs= new aws.SQS({ region: "us-east-2" });
```

Comment: FIFO queues seem to require the [SDK from 2016-11-17 or later](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Amazon-SQS/9087335643077522).  What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... I change to var sqs= new aws.SQS({ region: "us-east-2", apiVersion: "2016-11-17" }); Same result though.

Comment: Same result for var sqs= new aws.SQS({ region: "us-east-2", apiVersion: "2012-11-05" });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same error using Lambda (hence finding your post).  Wondering if they forgot to refresh the native SDK, I uploaded the latest version of the SDK(2.7.7) with my function and the error went away.

Since uploading the SDK removes the ability to edit in Lambda, I then deleted it and re-uploaded the function the error came back :(.

So for now, if you want to use it with Lambda, you have to include the SDK with your deployment package.

Comment: For Node.js, installing the latest aws-sdk using npm worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed passing "MessageGroupId" parameter. You should pass Message group id as a parameter. It is mandatory for FIFO.
Please refer the below-mentioned link,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sqs-2012-11-05.html#sendmessage